# Deploy multiple war

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, web-deployment, wildfly

Which best way to deploy multiple (war) into WildFly Server/JBoss 7?

The **war content are equals**, difference is the access to URL and database.

```
War 1: http://localhost:8080/war1
War 2: http://localhost:9080/war2
War 3: http://localhost:10080/war3
War 4: http://localhost:11080/war4
```

Actually I do:

```
 standalone.bat
-Djboss.server.base.dir=%STANDALONE_INSTANCE%
-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=%STANDALONE_INSTANCE%\log\boot.log
-Dlogging.configuration=%STANDALONE_INSTANCE%\configuration\logging.properties
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000
```

This way, 
I need duplicate the standalone folder with another name,
however is the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [domain](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Domain+Setup) servers, but why does each war need to run on a different server? You can deploy multiple wars onto the same standalone instance.

Comment: Can I deploy multiple wars into the same standalone instance with different ports?

Comment: No. All applications will be available on all ports the server is listening on.

Comment: So I couldn't to use em same standalone. 
I need that application uses different ports. In this case, the better choice is domain?

Comment: You could if you want to have a central management point. I can't say I understand the use case of having applications on different ports though :)

Comment: The scenario that I'm unfortunately is that. 
I agree with you, have a central management is better choice. 
The company has a proxy and for uses it to expose a new url to final user, this requires the proxy access AJP/HTTP port.

Have you got an example with domain?

Comment: Have a look at the docs https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Documentation and http://www.jboss.org for more information. I'm definitely not a domain expert :)